# How can I allow the user to input Numeric (with/without decimal point) only. OR numeric with 'K'/'B'

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I've been searching through Stack Overflow, but I can't get the right answer to my question.

How can I allow the user to input a number or number with 'K (Thousands)' or 'M (Millions)'?

I've tried using patterns, RegExp, etc.

Is there a regular expression for this? I tried using `^[0-9]*$` and also `^[0-9\K\M]*$`, but I don't know if it is the correct expression.

Comment: `^\d+(\.\d+)?(K|M|B)?$`

Comment: post some valid inputs.

Comment: I'd use `/^\d*\.?\d+[KM]?$/` - it matches `.05` and can easily be extended to support negative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you mean this,

```js
document.write(/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?[KM]?$/.test('121K') + '<br/>');
document.write(/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?[KM]?$/.test('121.7M') + '<br/>');
document.write(/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?[KM]?$/.test('121.45') + '<br/>');
```

Comment: works perfectly for regexp tester. gonna try it on js. 
thanks!
also, i just added [kKMm] to allow lowercase

Comment: no need for that , just add case-insensitive modifier `i`  `document.write(/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?[KM]?$/i.test('121m') + '<br/>');`

Comment: ohhh. i see. thank you, i'm just having trouble implementing it on my js. :)

Comment: @Hitori make a jsfiddle like, I'll try to help u :-)

Comment: Hi thank you!, 
heres my fiddle.
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/ca74k37L/)

ive been trying to prevent or replace the old input when matches fails. 
i can't do it in reversed

Comment: @Hitori before submitting the form , you have to check for that particular text box does not contain a dot at the last.

Answer (score 2):

This will work

```
^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*([KMB])?$
```

*JS Code*

```js
var re = /^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*([KMB])?$/; 
var str = '1234.567K';

var result = str.match(re);
document.writeln(result + '<br>')
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/6cYmZ8)**